# How to remove a vote?

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes

I accidently voted up an answer. So I tried to vote down but the answer gets -1 if I vote down. Is there a way to undo the upvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unupvote (and undownvote) a question or answer within a certain time frame by simply clicking the correct vote button.

If that period has lapsed, the question or answer must be edited in order to be voted on again.

Comment: Thanks I did not know we can click on same button and unupvote. :)